# Sticky.js for a button fixed at top

Tags: javascript, jquery, sticky

I'm trying to make sticky.js make a button fixed when scrolled.

Dev site: http://gameofjoes.com/LAW/1/
Element: Red button in the middle
Desired behavior: Button fixed on top when scrolled down.

JS: Sticky JS http://stickyjs.com/

--Added to the source code--

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$("#sticker").sticky({topSpacing:70});
```

});

jquery and sticky.js sourced too

---

I'm not sure if I need to add to the CSS style sheet for the "sticker" div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it needs any specific CSS (it seems to write the styles inline) however you do need to target your button with the code you're pasting, e.g. by adding the "sticker" id to it like so:

```
<div id="sticker" class="mbr-section-btn text-center">
    <a class="btn btn-md btn-secondary display-2" href="tel:17277865000">CLICK TO CALL (727)-786-5000</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. But I got the sticky and scroll element working. But now I have a z-index issue with the button hiding behind the middle elements. http://www.gameofjoes.com/LAW/mirror-2/

Comment: You will have to move the button outside of the wrapping ".container.align-center" div (so that it's at the same level as the .mbr-arrow element) in order to be able to position it over the top of the following content. You might need to tweak the styles a little after you move it but that should allow you to do what you need. By the way if the answer worked for the original solution would you mind accepting? Thanks :)